# Complement of a grammar Σ and Language L equal to L

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages

I have a problem that says: 
Prove that exists only one language L where for every alphabet Σ, we have that L = complement(ΣL). (L= (ΣL)').

I know that the complement of a language L, is L' = Σ* - L, but with this definition i don't know how to find the language that satisfies the condition because Σ* is an infinite language and this confuses me.
I also find out that the complement of a recursive language is the same recursive language but i don't know if this have any relation.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Is $\Sigma$ a grammar or an alphabet?

Comment: Is an alphabet, sorry :)

Comment: Your question is still unclear. If you define the complement of $L$ as $\Sigma^* - L$, which is correct, then $\Sigma$ is the alphabet of the language. But then the condition "for every alphabet" does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

$L$ contains the empty word because $\Sigma L$ cannot. Then $\Sigma L$ contains each one-letter word. That means $L$ contains none of them. So, $\Sigma L$ contains no two-letters word. So $L$ contains them all. And so on...

Comment: Thank you very much i understand now :)